# Openshift: Change in trigger behavior between 3.6.1 and 3.7.1

Tags: openshift

I have two Openshift environments that I publish to from a Gitlab pipeline. Let's call the first one DEV and it runs Openshift v3.7.1+c2ce2c0-1. The second one is INT and runs v3.6.1+008f2d5. Recently DEV got upgraded from 3.6.1 to 3.7.1 and after that I noticed a strange change in the behavior of redeployment triggers.

In short, what I see is that existing deployments in the DEV environment are triggered to redeploy with an "Image changed" message when an unchanged deployment config template is applied and while the Docker image also remains unchanged. This means that for example a MongoDB or Jenkins deployment recreates all containers and loses all data with every run of the CI pipeline.

Yes, there is the theoretically the possibility to use persistent volumes but the Openshift installations are not under my control. The point here is that redeployments happen when neither image nor configuration changes.

The command that I am using from Gitlab is this:

```
oc process -f openshift-mongodb-ephemeral.yml -v MONGODB_DATABASE=mydb -v DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME=mongodb -l template=northbound-mongodb | oc apply -f -
```

Here is one of the deployment config templates:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
labels:
  template: mongodb-ephemeral-template
metadata:
  annotations:
    description: |-
      MongoDB database service, without persistent storage. For more information about using this template, including OpenShift considerations, see https://github.com/sclorg/mongodb-container/blob/master/3.2/README.md.

      WARNING: Any data stored will be lost upon pod destruction. Only use this template for testing
    iconClass: icon-mongodb
    openshift.io/display-name: MongoDB (Ephemeral)
    tags: database,mongodb
  creationTimestamp: 2017-03-14T11:25:13Z
  name: mongodb-ephemeral
  resourceVersion: "483"
  selfLink: /oapi/v1/namespaces/openshift/templates/mongodb-ephemeral
  uid: e41b7f8e-08a8-11e7-9120-000d3a266151
objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    name: ${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: mongo
      nodePort: 0
      port: 27017
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 27017
    selector:
      name: ${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    name: ${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      name: ${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          name: ${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}
      spec:
        containers:
        - capabilities: {}
          env:
          - name: MONGODB_USER
            value: ${MONGODB_USER}
          - name: MONGODB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: database-password
                name: myproject-secrets
          - name: MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: database-admin-password
                name: myproject-secrets
          - name: MONGODB_DATABASE
            value: ${MONGODB_DATABASE}
          image: ' '
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            tcpSocket:
              port: 27017
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          name: mongodb
          ports:
          - containerPort: 27017
            protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -i
              - -c
              - mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/$MONGODB_DATABASE -u $MONGODB_USER -p $MONGODB_PASSWORD
                --eval="quit()"
            initialDelaySeconds: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: ${MEMORY_LIMIT}
          securityContext:
            capabilities: {}
            privileged: false
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/mongodb/data
            name: ${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}-data
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - emptyDir:
            medium: ""
          name: ${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}-data
    triggers:
    - imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
        - mongodb
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: mongodb:${MONGODB_VERSION}
          namespace: ${NAMESPACE}
        lastTriggeredImage: ""
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange
  status: {}
parameters:
- description: Maximum amount of memory the container can use.
  displayName: Memory Limit
  name: MEMORY_LIMIT
  required: true
  value: 512Mi
- description: The OpenShift Namespace where the ImageStream resides.
  displayName: Namespace
  name: NAMESPACE
  value: openshift
- description: The name of the OpenShift Service exposed for the database.
  displayName: Database Service Name
  name: DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME
  required: true
  value: mongodb
- description: Name of the MongoDB database accessed.
  displayName: MongoDB Database Name
  name: MONGODB_DATABASE
  required: true
  value: sampledb
- description: Version of MongoDB image to be used (2.4, 2.6, 3.2 or latest).
  displayName: Version of MongoDB Image
  name: MONGODB_VERSION
  required: true
  value: "3.2"
- description: Name of user to access MongoDB.
  displayName: MongoDB user
  name: MONGODB_USER
  required: true
  value: "mongouser"
```

The *oc process* and *oc apply* commands get executed with each execution of the Gitlab CI pipeline. The pipeline triggers whenever someone merges into e.g. the *develop* branch. I would like to keep this behavior because this guarantees if someone changes the configuration of MongoDB, Jenkins, etc. those get updated and redeployed automatically (in which case a loss of data is acceptable).

Does anybody know what change in OS could have prompted this change in behavior and how to achieve the old behavior again?

Comment: What happens if you remove ``creationTimestamp``, ``lastTriggeredImage`` and ``status`` entries from the ``DeploymentConfig``, and possibly also ``image``? These carry state information and by replacing the existing values, causing potential config or image change triggers due to it think things have changed and that a new deployment should be run.

Comment: Also, what is the intent wth re-applying the whole ``DeploymentConfig``? I wouldn't really regard this as typical. What specific fields are you using this to potentially update? There is likely a better way of doing this.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks for the suggestions. I will try them out. Regarding reapplying the deployment config, I agree it doesn't make so much sense for MongoDB but there are other deployments like Jenkins where we more routinely change their configuration, and at least on some occasions those changes are required by other changes such as in test scripts. From that perspective it made sense to us to apply the deployment configs for those more infrastructure-like services with every CI run. About MongoDB specifically, it was just that this template here was the shortest one I have available.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Your suggestions did the trick, the deployments don't get recreated anymore unless there is truly a change in image or configuration. Feel free to turn your comment into an answer, which I'll mark as such then.

Comment: BTW, how did you create the template file in the first place? Did you start by using ``oc export deployment/deploymentname --as-template templatename``? The ``oc export --as-template`` command isn't perfect and is still a good idea to to clean up the output further, but it should drop fields which are an issue. The ``image`` field may still be an issue though depending on how triggers work.

Comment: A coworker of mine created it but in general we just take the YAML from "Edit YAML" in the Openshift web UI and clean it up. Templates exported from the CLI contain marginally less data than YAML from the UI, and all the fields you pointed out are still present in templates from the CLI and will lead to the observed behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Credits go to Graham Dumpleton who answered my question, albeit through a comment. Since I did not hear back from him I am leaving this answer myself for completeness' sake.*

After removing the entries

- creationTimestamp
- lastTriggeredImage
- status
- image

from the deployment config template, the unwanted redeployments stopped. I do not know which entry specifically started triggering the behavior in Openshift 3.7.1 but in any case, these four entries are information generated during an Openshift deployment process and should not be in a template to begin with.